# Validate multiple concatenated XML in one file

Tags: xml, bash, validation, xmlstarlet, xmllint

Multiple XML files were concatenated into one file, see below a demo example. How it is possible to validate it using either `xmlstarlet` or `xmllint` command?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes" ?>
<BookHeaderMsg xmlns:xsi="THE URL" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="NAME.xsd">
  <BookHdr>
     <tag>value</tag>
     <tag2>value</tag2>
  </BookHdr>
  <Payload>
     <payloadTag>value</payloadTag>
     <payloadTag2>value</payloadTag2>
  </Payload>
</BookHeaderMsg>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes" ?>
<BookTransfer xmlns:xsi="THE URL" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="NAME.xsd">
  <BookHdr>
     <tag>value</tag>
     <tag2>value</tag2>
  </BookHdr>
  <Payload>
     <payloadTag>value</payloadTag>
     <payloadTag2>value</payloadTag2>
  </Payload>
</BookTransfer>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes" ?>
<BookTransfer xmlns:xsi="THE URL" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="NAME.xsd">
  <BookHdr>
     <tag>value 1</tag>
     <tag2>value 2</tag2>
  </BookHdr>
  <Payload>
     <payloadTag>value 1</payloadTag>
     <payloadTag2>value 2</payloadTag2>
  </Payload>
</BookTransfer>
```

I tried `xmlstarlet val Filename` and also `xmllint --valid Filename` both returned invalid. However, if I split each XML into separate files then they are valid (Unfortunately splitting is not feasible).

Comment: Well, in your example 3 valid files were concatenated into one invalid file... Maybe change the concatenation method.

Comment: @JackFleeting unfortunately I cannot change the layout.

Comment: Then you may out of luck. I don't know of any xml parser that can handle malformed xml, though they may be out there somewhere.

Comment: @JackFleeting Actually there is an approach such as to iterate to the files and read each file, then split/extract every xml document out of it, and finally use `xmlstarlet` or `xmllint` for validation. However, I am dealing with 100000 of such files and it might be a very time consuming process. I thought maybe the existing tools are able to handle such cases but apparently it seems they don't :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to validate XML files combined of multiple of other XML documents following the steps:

1. Create a loop to iterate through the files
2. Use `csplit` command to split XML documents from the combined file
3. Validate the split XML documents from step 2 using `xmlstarlet` command and redirect its output to a log file
4. Remove the split XML documents from step 2 using `rm` command
5. Repeat the above processes for other files

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash

SOURCE_DIR="./src"
LOG_DIR="./log"


files=()
while IFS='' read -r -d ''
do
        files+=("$REPLY")
done < <(find "$SOURCE_DIR" -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.xml" -printf '%p\0' | sort -zn)

total="${#files[@]}"
echo "start validating $total files" > "$LOG_DIR/summary.log"
counter=0
for file in "${files[@]}"
do
        ((counter++))
        # extract
        csplit "$file" --prefix="$file" --suffix-format='_%03d.xml.txt' --keep-files --elide-empty-files '/<?xml/' '{*}' &>/dev/null
        echo "$counter of $total working on $file"
        echo "$counter of $total working on $file" >> "$LOG_DIR/summary.log"
        # validate
        xmlstarlet val "$SOURCE_DIR"/*.xml.txt >> "$LOG_DIR/summary.log"

        # clean up
        rm "{$SOURCE_DIR}"/*.xml.txt
done
```